# The lonely pipe that should not be there

Tags: bug, blog

In every blog post, there are links to previous and next posts in the very bottom, under the tags and above the comments. All good.

However, when this is the latest blog post it got no next post yet the separator appears:

> [image]

I know it's small, but I can't stop staring at it. Can it please be removed when not needed?

([current latest blog post to see it in action](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/07/please-welcome-jmac-community-manager-of-the-rising-sun))

Comment: I will come to your house and beat you with a giant pipe. — Jeff Atwood

Comment: @Gilles believe it or not, but what you said is very relevant these days and we do have giant pipes hitting our houses. LOL

Comment: I noticed it too, but more as a worm with tetanus.